# How to Add a read-only Property to Database first Entity Framework 6 metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

i'm learning MVC and EF6 on my own, actually i'm following the tutorials on asp.net site that are very helpful. Today i was following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application). This is with code-first approach, but i'm doing this with database first approach. so i've followed the instructions to add the following read-only property to the Model, in my case to the model's metadata.

```
[Display(Name = "Full Name")]
public string FullName
{
      get
      {
         return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName;
      }
}
```

but when i try to Access the students page i got this error:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: The associated metadata type for type 'MVCEF6DBFirst.Models.Student' contains the following unknown properties or fields: FullName. Ensure that the names of these members match the names of the properties of the main type.

I know that there is an error with the property recently added so i googled it but i can't find a correct solution to this.

Could you tell me how i should add this property to my model

thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want is make available read only property for your Model? If that the case create a partial class and add this property and put [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped] attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the FullName column doesn't exist in the database table which means no property FullName exists in your EF model Student class you'll get this error.

1. I doubt you can achieve what you want using metadata-approach. But you can modify the way your properties are rendered in a view. If the following is your EF model class:

   ```
   public partial class Student
   {   
     public string FullName 
     {             
       get;
       set;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Then create another partial class called Student and place it in the same assembly(folder) but in a different file with a different file name.
   it'd look like this:

   ```
   [MetadataType(typeof(StudentMetadata))]
   public partial class Student
   {
   }

   public class StudentMetadata
   {
       [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
       public string FullName { get; set; }          
   }
   ```

then if you render your EF model Student class in a view

```
@model Models.Student
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

The name of the property will be displayed the way you wanted:

If you want to prevent user from editing the field by making it readonly, you may want to use this

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName, new{ disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

I am not sure how to achieve the same effect with Html.EditorForModel

Alternatively if you still want a property FullName made up of other two properties FirstName and LastName I'd try:

1. Your EF model class:

   ```
   public partial class Student
   {
    public string FirstName
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string SecondName
    {
       get; set;
    }
   ```

   }
2. Class extending Student class:

   ```
   public class StudentChild : Student
   {

   [Display(Name="User name")]
   public String FullName
   {
       get { return FirstName + ", " + SecondName; }
   }
   ```

   }
3. Then in your view:

   ```
   @model StudentChild

   @Html.DisplayForModel()
   ```

I am not sure the latter is the perfect approach as in the case that your underlying database schema changes then you need to modify your child class.

Comment: Thanks @sergik your approach was very useful. In addition i tried another approach that could be useful. (Posted as answer below)

Answer (score 0):

As i commented in the @sergik's answer i've found another approach to get this work (based on @sergik's answer).

1. EF Model Class

```
public class StudentMetadata
{                

}
```

2. Declare a partial class

```
[MetadataType(typeof(StudentMetadata))]    
    public partial class Student    
    {    
       [Display(Name = "Full Name")]    
       public string FullName    
       {    
          get    
          {    
             return LastName + ", " + FirstName;    
          }    
       }    
    }
```

3. add DataAnnotations reference to this class

```
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

4. Run Project. This is the result
   [image: Result addindg a read-only property to student class Database-First EF6]

Both @Sergik's and me answers were tested and both Works well.

Hope to be useful for other people.